# Excluding R.java from EMMA filter when in generated base package

Tags: android, jenkins, code-coverage, emma

I have an Android project, running EMMA for code coverage on a Jenkins build.

My problem is setting up a filter that excludes R.java without excluding any other R* packages and classes.

This is my package layout:

```
com.akodiakson.base (this pkg and two files come from the gen folder, not an actual part of the code base)
--R.java
--BuildConfig.java
com.akodiakson.base.alpha
com.akodiakson.base.beta
com.akodiakson.base.champ
--Repeat.java
(many other packages)
com.akodiakson.base.roger
(many other packages)
```

This is my EMMA filter:

```
<property name="emma.filter" value ="
       +*.akodiakson.base.*, 
       -*.akodiakson.base.*R*"/>
```

This, however, inadvertently will exclude com.akodiakson.base.roger and Repeat.java

Ideally, I would only have to explicitly exclude "com.akodiakson.base" without having to explicitly include any other R*.java classes and packages (see below for non-ideal explicity-everything filter).

This is not ideal (will not include roger):

```
<property name="emma.filter" value ="
       +*.akodiakson.base.*, 
       -*.akodiakson.base.*R*",
       +*.akodiakson.base.roger.*,
       +*.akodiakson.base.Repeat"/>
```

I have tried many combinations without much luck, including:

```
-*akodiakson.base.R$
-*akodiakson.base.R.java
-~.*\.R\$.*
```

I have seen all of the canonical posts here and at "6.2. Coverage filters"

This filter lives in the build file of my test project.

Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing property to look like this?

```
<property name="emma.filter" value ="
       +*.akodiakson.base.*, 
       -*.akodiakson.base.R.java"/>
```

Comment: I mentioned that in the "many combinations without much luck" section, gave it another attempt, but still no luck. 'til the ideal solution comes up, I'm going with a whitelist/explicit-inclusion strategy-- living with the downfall of another developer potentially adding a new package and not modifying the whitelist.